# How can I get data attribute as size

Tags: css, attr

I am trying

```
[main role="main"  class="container" data-margin="20vw"]

main{
    margin-top:attr(data-margin) !important;
}
```

Do you know why this is not working?

By the way `>` are not working in the editor?

Comment: please be more clear: what is not working? which is the expected result? what should represent that first line of code you've posted? HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The use of `attr()` is limited to the use with the `content` property in CSS 2.1.

Although [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#attr-notation) defines a broader use, it is also listed under *“the following features are at-risk, and may be dropped during the CR period”* in the same document.

Since there is no relevant number of *existing* implementations, it is likely that this will be dropped again.